# Refresh div with AJAX after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to show the loading img before AJAX response every time I submit the form. The problem is that img appears only on the first submission.

This is my code :

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value ){
         $('#response').html(' loading...');
            var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;

    });    
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $(".ajax")[0].reset();
            $("#response").hide();

        }
    });
    return false;    
});
```

Comment: $('#response').html(' loading...'),show();

Comment: you just fill up the content on hidden div. everytime you need to show it like  LShetty said.

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing `response` section after hiding it in the first time

use this line

```
 $("#response").show();
```

in the beginning

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){

        $("#response").show();

        /* bla bla your code bla bla
        ............................
        */


});
```